# clustat -x equivalent in rhel 7 pacemaker

Tags: cluster-computing, pacemaker, corosync

There was a command clustat -x in rhel 6 cluster which gives "last_transition_str" of a resource.

`<group name="service:MNGT" state="112" state_str="started" flags="0" flags_str="" owner="mifeas01" last_owner="mifeas02" restarts="0" last_transition="1551262689" last_transition_str="Wed Feb 27 11:18:09 2019"/>
    <group name="service:MRFC" state="112" state_str="started" flags="0" flags_str="" owner="mifeas02" last_owner="mifeas01" restarts="1" last_transition="1551264585" last_transition_str="Wed Feb 27 11:49:45 2019"/>
  </groups>
</clustat>`

I couldn't find any RHEL 7 pacemaker command to get mentioned above value.

Answer (score 0):

Last transition change state is specific to individual resources of a resource group.

Use the following command:

```
crm_resource --resource=<resource_name> -O | grep -i 'last-rc-change'
```